# can I hide a method to some environments with conditional imports?

Tags: dart

I have a private Dart generic package that can be imported in any platform, be it Flutter, Web or server apps using conditional imports.

However, I would like to hide the methods to some platforms.
Today, when those methods are called in those platforms, it throws exceptions.
I would like to avoid that by hiding them.

Is it possible somehow?

A hack that I know is that by importing dart:io, the project won't compile in web for example. Seems a bit ugly, but is already better than knowing only at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Your idea I would say that it is the best possible, and it doesn't even seem to me a hack (simply those who have as target dart or flutter native can import an additional file, not available when the target is the web).

Support for conditional imports/exports is currently very limited (and has become even more limited by switching to Dart 2, before you could use any constant as condition, not just the properties of `dart.library`), and it is not possible to do know the compiler that different APIs are available based on the platform. Also famous packages like sqflite have adopted naive solutions such as require different imports based on the mobile VS Desktop platform (if a developer then wants to use only the APIs available in all platforms, can wrap everything in a file with a conditional import, and only expose the common APIs. In reality it is a bit more complicated than that, but the substance is this).

The Dart Analyzer does not even verify the conditional imports, so that in the compilation phase you may have errors not reported by the IDE or vice versa, and as a condition you can use non-existent references (for example `if (xxx) 'my_import.dart'`) without neither the Dart Analyzer nor the compiler signal the error; in this case the compiler will consider the condition always false, which can lead to bugs.

This to say that your solution is not bad at all, since the support is currently so lacking.